# backtick marker navigation "not an editor command"

Tags: vimscript

I  am trying to create a vimL script where, among other things, I need to copy the text between two markers such as in

```
:'a,'by
```

however, I want to copy between columns of the marker positions (characterwise). I have read several times I can use backticks as

```
:`a,`by
```

But is returning "Not an editor command". Even simple

```
:`
```

returns "Not an editor command", although `:'` goes to the correct line.

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, ex-commands always work linewise. There is an open issue in the todo list about it, however until now it has never been implemented. For `:s` command you can make use of the `/%V` and `/\%c` regex atom to make sure it matches within a certain area. Other ex commands don't work on columns. In that case, simple use the normal mode command. That should work without problems.

Comment: yeap, executing exe `normal! (backtick)a,(backtick)by'."\<cr>"` works (i don't know how to  write my answer because backticks format the answer. I used (backtick) to mean the backtick instead)